# While loop in Map Algebra ArcPy, associate output raster name with input raster

Tags: arcpy, loop, map-algebra

I have an ArcMap document open with LandSat images from one day in different bands as rasters. They're named:

```
LC80541162014003LGN00_B1.TIF
LC80541162014003LGN00_B2.TIF
```

and so on, B1 through to B9 (bands 1 to 9).

I want to do a calculation on each band and the result of the calculation should be a new raster for each band, with the name of it indicating which band it is. This is what I'm trying, but the string in the output name disallows the process. How do I achieve the same result, get output of TOA_B1, TOA_B2 etc.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy import mapping
from arcpy.sa import *
i = list(range(1,10))
while i<10:
        TOAB_ + str(i) = Raster('LC80541162014003LGN00_B' + str(i)+ '.TIF')*2
```

To be clear, the calculation within it works on its own

```
Raster('LC80541162014003LGN00_B' + str(i)+ '.TIF')*2
```

I have simplified the script here for clarity, I know I could do each calculation separately but for various reasons it will be much more efficient to do it in a loop of some kind.

Comment: looks like a typo to me in your output rater name, you have an extra i. Try: toad_ + str(i)  = .....

Comment: I'd use arcpy. Raster()

Comment: You can't assign a value to an operation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956876/737471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` with `for` loop to count the number of rasters inside a workspace and in the same time get the raster bands as objects. `enumerate` by default starts with 0, but you need to start with 1, so you have to write `enumerate(rasterlist, start=1)`. Then you can use `Spatial Analysts -> Times function` to multiply each band with 2. The variable assigned to multiplication can be saved to the target workspace. Here you need to pass (i) when you save to a new file with a new name.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env

# Set the current workspace
env.workspace = r"C:\PathTO\Landsat\Bands1_9"

# Check out Spatial extension 
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Get a list of raster images of Landsat Bands from the workspace
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()

# Get a count and the raster obtained from rsterlist
for i, raster in enumerate(rasterlist, start=1):
    print i,raster

# Multiply each Landsat band by 2
    toa = Times(raster,2)

# Save the output Landsat bands to the target workspace
    toa.save(r"C:\PathTO\Landsat\Bands1_9\TOA\TOA_B"+ str(i)+".tif")
```

The out put will be as follows:

```
TOA_B1.tif
TOA_B2.tif
TOA_B3.tif
TOA_B4.tif
TOA_B5.tif
TOA_B6.tif
TOA_B7.tif
TOA_B8.tif
TOA_B9.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

`'TOAB_'` need to be in quotes since it is a string.

I suspect that you need to separate the `TOAB_ + stri(i)` part.  Maybe `toa = 'TOAB_' + stri(i)` on the first line and then `toa = Raster('LC80541162014003LGN00_B' + str(i)+ '.TIF')*2` on the second line.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. There's no error, but no output. (If it did run, would this not just assign a string to toa then replace it by assigning a raster to a toa. i.e. I would just have a raster called toa, not TOAB_1.

Comment: @Beardsley you are right about it assigning then re-assigning a value.